# Can PDN Connectivity Request for IMS APN be initiated if VoPS support is not there in Attach Accept?

Tags: lte, apn, ims

I have a scenario where UE requests for the VoPS service in the Attach Request, but the network is sending eps_netwk_feature_support_incl as 0, which as per my knowledge signifies that the voice service over PS is not supported.

Further, I can see that the UE is initiating the PDN connectivity Request for the "ïms" apn.
My question is if it is normal for the UE to initiate the PDN connectivity request for the "ims"  APN. What is the use case of this?

Answer (score 1):

eps_netwk_feature_support_incl indicates whether network supports the features like ims over ps, emergency call over ims.

If the value of this information element is zero then network does not support any ims related features in that particular tracking area.
There is no point in initiating ims pdn if network does not supports it.

So,UE should not initiate IMS PDN.